# generated files from ANTLR conflict in visual studio between release and debug modes

Tags: visual-studio, build, antlr

I use `ANTLR4` with `Visual Studio` and `C#`. During the build process the `ANTLR4` tool generates 6 `C#` source files (i.e Parser, Lexer, Visitor, Listener etc) that correspond to the parser the `ANTLR` generates. This files are generated in the obj/Debug directory of the project (assuming that Debug mode is chosen). I add these files as links in the solution explorer for inspecting the generated code.

If i try to change to release mode `ANTLR4` generates the same files in obj/Release directory of the project and these files are in conflict (dublicate classes in the same namespace) with the files produced in obj/Debug directory.

**The question is:**

When I am in release mode having done the aforementioned actions, Is there any way to exclude generated files in the solution explorer from debug mode (while on release mode) or I have to manually exclude the obj/Debug directory from the solution explorer in order to avoid conflict?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled over the same problem. The main problem, have linked the files to the projects DEBUG configuration. So the links are still there when you switch to RELEASE configuration and now you have duplicate definitions in you project. The visibles in the obj/DEBUG path and the invisibles in the obj/RELEASE path

I don't know any solution to solve this on the VS-GUI. But it is possible to patch the cproj file to get an acceptable solution:

First the orginal part:

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DataRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SpreadsheetErrorListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SpreadsheetVisitor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetBaseListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetBaseVisitor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetLexer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetParser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetVisitor.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

Yours should look similar.

I splitted the ItemGroups it to this:

```
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="DataRepository.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SpreadsheetErrorListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="SpreadsheetVisitor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Compile Include="obj\Release\SpreadsheetBaseListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Release\SpreadsheetBaseVisitor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Release\SpreadsheetLexer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Release\SpreadsheetListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Release\SpreadsheetParser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Release\SpreadsheetVisitor.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetBaseListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetBaseVisitor.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetLexer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetListener.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetParser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="obj\Debug\SpreadsheetVisitor.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
...
```

In VS both directories are visible, but only one is used for Intellisense and during compile.

The currently selected files are shown with the "openers" (Sorry don't know the correct name)

[DEBUG configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STgGV.png)

[RELEASE configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzaCG.png)

Doesn't look nice but solves the problem.

The disadvantage:

Every time you add new configurations you must patch the cproj file again. But it is worth to do it this way, cause Intellisense, Resharper and all other nice little helper will work.